# ActionMode Material theme in pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design, android-actionmode

I'm displaying an ActionMode via this code in a Kitkat 4.4.2 device with this code from a Fragment, targetSDK 21. I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as the default theme in my app:

```
actionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(EventsFragment2.this);
```

`ActionMode` is displayed but as a Light Holo themed widget. So I thought maybe the `appcompat` library doesn't support `ActionMode` yet. But then, in the same application, while selecting the some text in an `EditText`, the material `ActionMode` with all the fancy flat icons and animations where shown. So the problem is with my code. What am I doing wrong here?

*Note*: I'm using `ActionBarActivity` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought, just use the following code:

```
ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
actionMode = activity.startSupportActionMode(EventsFragment2.this);
```

Make sure that you use the correct import, ie..

```
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
```